# Django-reversion and south compatibility

Tags: django, django-models, compatibility, django-south, django-reversion

Does [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) work well with south migrations?
Are django-reversion and south compatible?

Current versions:
- reversion - 1.2.1
- south     - 0.7.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used django-reversion but I see no reason why it wouldn't be compatible.

Indeed, [these **updated** docs](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrations.html) from django-reversion detail on migrating from old versions of south and imply south and reversion can work fine together.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I also reached that page while Googling. I was hoping for a confirmation from someone who tried. Guess I'll go ahead and try it myself :)

Comment: Here's Dave Hall's answer to this Q: Schema migration tools are ignored by Reversion. If you add or change fields, it's all fine. If you remove a field, it breaks. This is the fault of Django's serialization framework, not Reversion. If you do remove a field from your model, delete the Reversion history for that model. Remember: Reversion is all about the DATA, not the schema.

Comment: The link is broken. That's again good example why giving only link without referring contents briefly is a bad idea.